# SimpleXmlElement Parsing Errors

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

Just had a WordPress site updated with the latest [Custom Contact Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-contact-forms/). After the update the site is no longer loading and I see these errors:

```
[27-Jun-2015 06:01:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 130: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: wphead line 1 and script in /storage/web/public/sites/www.site.nl/wp-content/themes/site/vihv/control/TControl.php on line 91
[27-Jun-2015 06:01:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;/script&gt; in /storage/web/public/sites/www.site.nl/wp-content/themes/site/vihv/control/TControl.php on line 91
[27-Jun-2015 06:01:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct():          ^ in /storage/web/public/sites/www.site.nl/wp-content/themes/site/vihv/control/TControl.php on line 91
[27-Jun-2015 06:01:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 148: parser error : Sequence ']]&gt;' not allowed in content in /storage/web/public/sites/www.site.nl/wp-content/themes/site/vihv/control/TControl.php on line 91
```

The first error refers to this function:

```
function GetXml() {
            try {
                $Xml = new SimpleXmlElement(TXml::MakeTree($this->GetData(), get_class($this)));
                return $Xml->asXml();
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                //print_r($this->GetData());
            }
        return "<".get_class($this)."/>";
        }
```

But these errors are only PHP warnings, not fatal errors. But I get the white screen of death anyways.

I am not familiar with XML and XML parsing. Theme was created by third party developer and have not been able to contact him as of yet. It has been a while since this theme has been created.
I did uncomment the print_r to see what would show and all was printed and the first array showing up was:

```
Array ( [THeadControl] => Array ( [wphead] => ]]> [template_url] => http://www.site.nl/wp-content/themes/site [title] => ) [TLeftBlockContainer] => Array ( [THeaderControl] => Array ( [siteurl] => http://www.site.nl [siteTitle] => VERLOSKUNDIGENPRAKTIJK site [headpic] => http://www.site.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/siteheader2.jpg [logoPhone] => http://www.site.nl/wp-content/themes/site/img/logo-phone.png ) [TSimpleMenuControl] => Array ( [menu] =>
```

And on line 130 I saw

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.site.nl/wp-includes/js/underscore.min.js?ver=1.6.0'></script>
```

I suspect that the plugin adds something to the header that causes the html tag errors / creating invalid XML.

**Update**
__construct() method addition here as suggested by @danbahrami

```
function __construct() {
        $Manager = TEventManager::getInstance();
        $Manager->AddListener($this);
        $this->SetEvent('OnGet', array($this,'OnGetEvent'));
        $this->SetEvent('OnPost', array($this,'OnPostEvent'));
        $this->SetEvent('OnDisplay', array($this,'OnDisplayEvent'));
        $this->SetEvent('OnBeforeDisplay', array($this,'OnBeforeDisplayEvent'));
        $this->SetEvent('OnEnable', array($this,'OnEnableEvent'));
        $this->SetEvent('OnDisable', array($this,'OnDisableEvent'));
        $this->SetEvent('OnCreate', array($this,'OnCreateEvent'));
        $this->SetEvent('OnRootTemplateLoad', array($this,'OnRootTemplateLoadEvent'));
        $this->SetEvent('OnDefaultPage', array($this,'OnDefaultPageEvent'));
        $this->OnCreate($this);
        }
```

The whole file TControl.php can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/VzirPbdx). How can I debug this error? is it possible to bypass the errors?

Comment: Read here https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug that using print_r for debuggin is not a great idea.. Will see if I can implement their suggestion, but would still love to hear other people's suggestions and an option to bypass the errors.

Comment: Actually it looks like the issue is coming from the __construct() method of the simpleXMLelement class. Could you include that method in your answer? As far as debugging goes get PHPStorm... You won't look back!

Comment: When I ran the site with plugin switched on with `echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";` as suggested here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php I saw `Caught exception: String could not be parsed as XML Caught exception: String could not be parsed as XML Caught exception: String could not be parsed as XML` Not helpful enough..

Comment: Opened issue at CCF https://github.com/tlovett1/custom-contact-forms/issues/143 to ask what Custom Contact Form adds to pages like home to figure out if invalid code is added and what invalid code is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Contact Forms added a JavaScript in CDATA Tags commented out like so `/* <![CDATA[ */` and `/* ]]> */` . There was also a bullet pasted as `&bull;` That choked the XML Parser. Seems the parser did not like the CDATA commented out this way.
To debug I had help from another developer who used

```
print("<pre>");
var_dump($this->GetData());
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
print($xml);
die();
```

but to test it he copied xml from output, saved to file and checked it out by separate script:

```
$xml = file_get_contents("qqq.xml");
$xml = str_replace("", "X", $xml);
$xml = preg_replace("@/\*.*\*/@", "", $xml);
$rr = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($rr);
```

Which printed errors or XML if everything OK. With the adjusted TConfig function with

```
$xml = $TXml->MakeTree($this->GetData(), get_class($this));
#$xml = str_replace("", "-", $xml);
#$xml = preg_replace("@/\*.*\*/@", "", $xml);
$xml = preg_replace("@/\*.*\*/@", "<!-- commented out -->", $xml);
                $Xml = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
                return $Xml->asXml();
            } catch(Exception $e) {
print("<pre>");
var_dump($this->GetData());
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
print($xml);
die();
```

all is working again. Preg replace was used to remove the offending CDATA code. Will see at a later stage if it can stay without the `/**/`.